# Convert Visual Web Developer project to Web Matrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Title pretty much sums it up. How can I do this? Any tools available that can do it? Or import/export settings? Any tips or pointers on how to go around doing this?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1769111.aspx/1 Use this link to get some help